# Always Running Out of Space in Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, delete, storage

I am a very new Ubuntu user and I am currently running Ubuntu on VirtualBox on a Mac:

[image: Details of the VirtualBox file]
[image: My Ubuntu storage]

There is literally nothing installed but a small program in my Ubuntu, Nevertheless, my storage (30 GB) is almost full. I ran `autoclean`, `autoremove`, `clean` and similar commands several times and the latest updates are installed.

What can I do to clean up some space without extending the storage capacity? Which files can I delete?

Comment: Can you add the output of the command `df -h`? A fresh install shouldn't take so much space.

Comment: Maybe the app crash logs have increased the same. I had once 25gb of crash logs in ubuntu.

Comment: Also the disk analyser in ubuntu is useful.

Comment: Stacer might be the best app to use in this case.